# Mysql query that inserts in multiple rows depending on the number of times defined

Tags: mysql

i want to run the query below depending on the number of items i key in, for example, i want to add 5 toys in the table, so the query will run 5 times.

My query looks like this:

```
$q = 'INSERT INTO StockDetails (stockNumber, quantity, items) VALUES (".$snumber.", "1", "toys")';
```

and i want to end up with a table like this:

```
ID      stockNumber       quantity      items
-----------------------------------------------
1        ST001               1           toys
2        ST001               1           toys
3        ST001               1           toys
4        ST001               1           toys
5        ST001               1           toys
```

so if i change the number of toys to ten, i will get a table with 10 rows.

please help.

Comment: What's the point of a quantity column whose value is always 1?

Answer (score 0):

If you want an `insert` query to be executed for specified number of times then it's better to wrap it inside a `function` and call that function with `number of rows` as one of the parameters, e.g.:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test`.`myfunction` $$
CREATE FUNCTION `test`.`myfunction` (count int, i_stockNumber varchar(20), i_quantity int, i_items int) RETURNS INT
DECLARE x INT;
SET x = 0;
BEGIN
    WHILE x <= count DO
        insert into StockDetails (stockNumber, quantity, items) values (i_stockNumber, i_quantity, i_items);
        SET x = x + 1;
    END WHILE;
  RETURN LAST_INSERT_ID();
END $$
```